# react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Cannot update a component (`BrowserRouter`) while rendering a different component (`Signin`)

Tags: react-router

Facing this Warning Message in React JS Application,
When it is navigating from one page to other page . I'm unable to find out its root cause or any alternative to avoid it.

react-dom.development.js:86
Warning: Cannot update a component (`BrowserRouter`) while rendering a different component (`Signin`)

Screenshot also attached FYR.
[copy of App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzTFr.png)

[Warning Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgbbur.com/RLOu5.png)

```
App.js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Signin from "./Components/Signin";
import Signup from "./Components/Signup";
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Display from "./Components/Display";
import Userlist from "./Components/Userlist";
import Userdetails from "./Components/Userdetails";
import WeatherApp from "./Components/WeatherApp";
import Password from "./Components/Password";
export const loginStatus = { login: false };
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="contact-background-image">
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/">
              <Route path="/" element={<Signin />}></Route>
              <Route path="/signin" element={<Signin />}></Route>
              <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
              <Route path="/display" element={<Display />} />
              <Route path="/userlist" element={<Userlist />} />
         <Route path="/userdetails" element={<Userdetails />} />
           <Route path="/weatherapp" element={<WeatherApp />} />
              <Route path="/password" element={<Password />} />
              <Route path="/*" element={<Signin />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;




Signin.js

import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { Icon } from "react-icons-kit";
import { eyeOff } from "react-icons-kit/feather/eyeOff";
import { eye } from "react-icons-kit/feather/eye";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { loginStatus } from "../App";

function Signin() {
  let URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8901/users";
  let LoginURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8901/login";

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [txtcustname, setTxtcustname] = useState("");
  const [errmsgcustname, setErrmsgcustname] = useState("");
  const [txtcustpass, setTxtcustpass] = useState("");
  const [errmsgcustpass, setErrmsgcustpass] = useState("");
  const [custnameflag, setCustnameflag] = useState(false);
  const [custpassflag, setCustpassflag] = useState(false);
  const [successmsg, setSuccessmsg] = useState("");
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);
  const [errormsg, setErrormsg] = useState("");
  const [custdetail, setcustdetail] = useState(null);
  const [type, setType] = useState("password");
  const [icon, setIcon] = useState(eyeOff);

  let changeValue = (event) => {
    const fieldName = event.target.name;
    switch (fieldName) {
      case "custname":
        setTxtcustname(event.target.value);

        validateCustName(event.target.value);

        break;

      case "custpass":
        setTxtcustpass(event.target.value);

        validateCustPass(event.target.value);

        break;
    }
  };

  let validateCustName = (value) => {
    if (value.length === 0) {
      setErrmsgcustname("Please check the username");
      setCustnameflag(false);
    } else {
      setErrmsgcustname("");
      setCustnameflag(true);
    }
  };

  let validateCustPass = (value) => {
    if (value.length === 0) {
      setErrmsgcustpass("Invalid Password");
      setCustpassflag(false);
    } else {
      setErrmsgcustpass("");
      setCustpassflag(true);
    }
  };

  let CredentialCheck = (e) => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    let user = txtcustname;
    let pass = txtcustpass;
    let postdata = {
      username: user,
      password: pass,
    };

    axios
      .post(LoginURL, postdata)
      .then((resp) => {
        if ((resp.data.validation = true)) {
          setCustnameflag(true);
          setCustpassflag(true);
        }
        Signincheck();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error: ", error);
        console.log("credcheck ERROR done here");
        setErrormsg("UserName or Password entered is Incorrect");
        alert("UserName or Password entered is Incorrect");
        setCustnameflag(false);
        setCustpassflag(false);
        setTxtcustpass("");
        setTxtcustname("");
      });
  };

  let Signincheck = () => {
    let usernamearray = [];
    let fulldata = [];
    if (custnameflag === false || custpassflag === false) {
      setErrormsg("Invalid Username and Passwords");
    } else if (custnameflag === true && custpassflag === true) {
      axios.get(URL).then((resp) => {
        fulldata = resp.data;
        fulldata.map((custfulldata) => {
          if (custfulldata.username === txtcustname) {
            usernamearray.push(custfulldata);
            console.log(usernamearray[0]);
            setSuccessmsg("Update detail");
            setcustdetail(usernamearray[0]);
            setSuccess(true);
            loginStatus.login = true;
            console.log(custdetail);
            console.log("User login details ");
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };

  const handleToggle = () => {
    if (type === "password") {
      setIcon(eye);
      setType("text");
    } else {
      setIcon(eyeOff);
      setType("password");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="button-right">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-light button-right"
          onClick={(e) => {
            navigate("/signup");
          }}
        >
          Not a member - SignUp
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="container">
        <div>
          <div
            className="card col-md-6 offset-md-3 "
            style={{ marginTop: "1vh", opacity: "0.9" }}
          >
            <div className="card-header bg-custom">
              <>
                {success ? (
                  navigate("/display", {
                    state: { name: txtcustname, id: custdetail._id },
                  })
                ) : (
                  <section>
                    <form>
                      <div>
                        <h1 className="formtitle" style={{ marginTop: "-1vh" }}>
                          SignIn{" "}
                        </h1>
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="custname">
                          UserName: <span className="text-danger">*</span>{" "}
                        </label>

                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="custname"
                          value={txtcustname}
                          onChange={changeValue}
                          className="form-control"
                          title="Please Enter your Username"
                          required
                        />
                        <span className="text-danger">{errmsgcustname}</span>
                      </div>

                      <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="custpass">
                          Password : <span className="text-danger">*</span>{" "}
                        </label>
                        <div className="row">
                          <div className="col">
                            <input
                              type={type}
                              name="custpass"
                              value={txtcustpass}
                              onChange={changeValue}
                              title="Please Enter your Password"
                              className="form-control"
                              style={{ width: "190%" }}
                              autoComplete="off"
                              required
                            />
                          </div>
                          <div className="col">
                            <span
                              className="flex justify-around items-center"
                              onClick={handleToggle}
                            >
                              <Icon
                                className="absolute mr-10"
                                icon={icon}
                                style={{
                                  marginLeft: "87%",
                                  marginTop: "1vh",
                                }}
                                size={25}
                              />
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <br />
                        <span className="text-danger">{errmsgcustpass}</span>
                      </div>

                      <button
                        className="btn btn-primary text-light"
                        type="button"
                        onClick={(e) => {
                          e.preventDefault();
                          CredentialCheck();
                        }}
                        disabled={!(custnameflag && custpassflag)}
                      >
                        Login
                      </button>
                      <br />
                    </form>
                  </section>
                )}
              </>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Signin;







Display.js


import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { useState } from "react";
// import axios from "axios";
// import WeatherApp from "./WeatherApp";
// import Signin from "./Signin";
// import Userlist from "./Userlist";
// import Userdetails from "./Userdetails";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigate, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { loginStatus } from "../App";

function Display() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  let data = location.state;
  console.log(data);
  return !loginStatus.login || !location.state ? (
    <Navigate to="/signin" replace={true} />
  ) : (
    <div>
      <div className=" button-right ">
        <button
          className="btn btn-light button-right "
          title="click here to update password"
          onClick={() => {
            console.log(data.id);
            navigate("/password", {
              state: {
                id: data.id,
                name: data.name,
              },
            });
          }}
          type="button"
        >
          Update Password
        </button>

        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-light button-right "
          onClick={() => {
            loginStatus.login = false;
            console.log("displaylogin check " + loginStatus.login);
            navigate("/signin");
          }}
        >
          SignOut
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className=" card col-md-6 offset-md-3" style={{ opacity: "0.9" }}>
        <div>
          <h3 style={{ margin: "5vh", color: "darkblue" }}>
            Hello {data.name},
          </h3>
          <h5 style={{ margin: "5vh" }}>
            House Konnect is an enterprise organization. We offer services in a
            range of options to suit their customers need across Australia.
            <br /> We provide connection survives on Electricity, Gas and Water
            <p>
              Including but not limited to: Fast speed internet, Water,
              Electricity and Gas supply services.
            </p>
          </h5>
          <p style={{ margin: "5vh" }}>
            To view/update your profile or weather details please click below
          </p>

          <div>
            <button
              type="button"
              title="Manage Users Details"
              className="btn btn-primary"
              hidden={data.name != "admin"}
              style={{ marginLeft: "2vw" }}
              onClick={() => {
                navigate("/Userlist", {
                  state: { id: data.id, name: data.name },
                });
              }}
            >
              Manage Users
            </button>

            <button
              type="button"
              title="Update Profile details"
              className="btn btn-primary"
              style={{ marginLeft: "2vw" }}
              onClick={() => {
                navigate("/Userdetails", {
                  state: { id: data.id, name: data.name },
                });
              }}
            >
              Update Profile
            </button>

            <button
              title="Get Weather Latest Update"
              className="btn btn-primary"
              style={{ marginLeft: "2vw" }}
              onClick={() => {
                navigate("/WeatherApp", {
                  state: { id: location.state.id, name: location.state.name },
                });
              }}
            >
              Weather details
            </button>

            <br />
          </div>
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Display;
```

Comment: I don't see why this post was closed, issue was clear enough given the provided details. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Signin` component you are invoking the `navigate` function during the component render, which is an unintentional side-effect.

```
return (
  <div>
    ...
    <div className="card-header bg-custom">
      <>
        {success ? (
          navigate("/display", {
            state: { name: txtcustname, id: custdetail._id },
          })
        ) : (
          <section>
            ...
          </section>
        )}
      </>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
);
```

You should render the `Navigate` component here though:

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

return (
  <div>
    ...
    <div className="card-header bg-custom">
      <>
        {success ? (
          <Navigate
            to="/display"
            state={{ name: txtcustname, id: custdetail._id }}
          />
        ) : (
          <section>
            ...
          </section>
        )}
      </>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
);
```

Really though, you could just issue the imperative navigation from the `signincheck` callback function.

Example refactor:

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();

...

const credentialCheck = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const postdata = {
    username: txtcustname,
    password: txtcustpass,
  };

  try {
    const resp = await axios.post(LoginURL, postdata)
    
    if (resp.data.validation) {
      setCustnameflag(true);
      setCustpassflag(true);
      signinCheck();
    }
  } catch(error){
    console.log("error: ", error);
    console.log("credcheck ERROR done here");
    setErrormsg("UserName or Password entered is Incorrect");
    alert("UserName or Password entered is Incorrect");
    setCustnameflag(false);
    setCustpassflag(false);
    setTxtcustpass("");
    setTxtcustname("");
  };
};

const signinCheck = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(URL);
    
  if (data.some(custfulldata => custfulldata.username === txtcustname)) {
    loginStatus.login = true;
    navigate(
      "/display",
      { state: { name: txtcustname, id: custfulldata._id } }
    );
  }
};

...

return (
  ...
  <div className="card-header bg-custom">
    <section>
      <form onSubmit={credentialCheck}>
        ...
        
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary text-light"
          type="submit"
          disabled={!(custnameflag && custpassflag)}
        >
          Login
        </button>
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>
  ...
);
```